# Select const value

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is it possible with Elasticsearch Nest to select an additional const value?
In Sql I would do:

```
SELECT constValue = 'test', * FROM table
```

How would I do this in Elasticsearch?

Comment: did you check script field?

Comment: Can you give an example of using the script field in this case?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because I need the value in the output. Of course I can loop over the results and add the value in the resulting objects, but that would create an extra loop which I would try to prevent.

Comment: Using something like a Script field for this now means that Elasticsearch needs to do additional (albeit, very small) work to return this extra field across the wire for every hit, in addition to increasing the payload across the wire. I'd personally be inclined to add on the caller side.